# how to record http traces from browser?

Tags: http, browser

are there any methods to record http traces that are issued from the browser?

I would be mainly interested in the GET / POST methods to understand the interaction with a webpage. Maybe helpful the browser I am using is FireFox.

Comment: The question is a duplicate. You might want to check: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722807/http-monitor-software-monitor-web-services/722876#722876](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722807/http-monitor-software-monitor-web-services/722876#722876)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647) or [Live HTTP Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) Firefox addons.

Comment: Just discovered HTTPFox today and have added it to my browser.  Usually use Live HTTP Headers for this sort of thing most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox: [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829)

Answer (score 0):

[HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com) is a commercial tool that will record traces in both IE and Firefox. There is also a free version available that shows basic information such as time charts, URLs accessed, the HTTP method and the status code returned from the server.

Disclaimer: This answer was provided by Simtec Limited, the makers of HttpWatch.